# How to get request body to be populated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a get response and in my api/cmsview it is not getting the object that my Axios is passing.

```
class CmsView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)


    this.state = {
        cmsObj: [],
        packageLid : props.location.state
    }
    var packageLid = this.props.location.state.packageLid
    console.log(packageLid.PACKAGE_LID) //this gets populated with data
    Axios.get('/api/cmsview', {packageLid})
    .then((response) => {
                this.setState({ cmsObj: response.data })
            })
   }
}
```

My `packageLid` does get populated with data, but when I do the Axios get:

in my cmsview.js

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body.packageLid.PACKAGE_LID) 
}
```

my `req.body.packageLid` does not get populated. Any idea why? It just outputs "undefined"

Comment: I suggest that you edit the title. Your issue is in request.body not being populated on the server side.

Comment: Thanks. It will be much easier to understand for new followers to the thread. As for the issue, I do agree with Anil that you might be listening on the wrong route. What happens if you update to `router.get('/api/cmsview', (req, res, next) ...` ?

Comment: the router.get just never gets called if I update it to that @VlatkoVlahek

Answer (score 0):

You need to put axios call in componentDidMount method.

```
componentDidMount() {
var packageLid = this.props.location.state.packageLid
console.log(packageLid.PACKAGE_LID) //this gets populated with data
Axios.get('/api/cmsview', {packageLid})
.then((response) => {
            this.setState({ cmsObj: response.data })
        })
  }
 }
```

Comment: Still getting undefined with this as well. Perhaps I cannot call req.body.packageLid.PACKAGE_LID ?

Comment: You are calling /api/cmsview from react and in api you have / . Fix it

Comment: the / gets called and /api/cmsview does not though. The problem is the object I am sending it, never gets populated